# How much data can I get with the Twitter Search API for one specific keyword?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want collect data from twitter using python Tweepy library.

I surveyed the rate limits for Twitter API,which is 180 requests per 15-minute.

What I want to know how many data I can get for one specific keyword?put it in another way , when I use the Tweepy.Cursor,when it'll stops?

I not saying the maths calculation(100 count * 180 request * 4 times/hour etc.) but the real experience.I found a view as follows:

"With a specific keyword, you can typically only poll the last 5,000 tweets per keyword. You are further limited by the number of requests you can make in a certain time period. "
http://www.brightplanet.com/2013/06/twitter-firehose-vs-twitter-api-whats-the-difference-and-why-should-you-care/

Is this correct(if this's correct,I only need to run the program for 5 minutes or so)? or I am needed to keep getting as many tweets as they are there(which may make the program keep running very long time)?

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely not be getting as many tweets as exist. The way Twitter limits how far back you can go (and therefore how many tweets are available) is with a minimum `since_id` parameter passed to the [`GET search/tweets`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) call to the Twitter API. In Tweepy, the [`API.search`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.search) function interfaces with the Twitter API. Twitter's `GET search/tweets` documentation has a lot of good info:

> There are limits to the number of Tweets which can be accessed through the API. If the limit of Tweets has occured since the since_id, the since_id will be forced to the oldest ID available.

In practical terms, Tweepy's `API.search` should not take long to get all the *available* tweets. Note that not all tweets are *available* per the Twitter API, but I've never had a search take up more than 10 minutes.